# How to count the null,na and nan values in each column of pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe as na,Nan and Null values .
Schema (Name:String,Rol.No:Integer,Dept:String
Example:

```
Name  Rol.No  Dept
priya  345     cse
James  NA       Nan
Null   567      NULL
```

Expected output as to columns name and count of null,na and nan values

```
Name 1
Rol.No 1
Dept 2
```

Comment: please provide data type schema of your dataframe ...

Comment: Schema (Name:String,Rol.No:Integer,Dept:String)

Comment: you can't have a "NA" as an integer ...

Comment: regardless of what strings you have I posted the solution below

Comment: for integer how it represents empty values

Comment: not following you ... i have provided the solution below to get total occurrences of whatever your data has it in that you want to count.

Answer (score 3):

Use `when()`

```py
spark.version
'2.3.2'

import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

schema = T.StructType([\
                          T.StructField("Name", T.StringType(), True),
                          T.StructField("RolNo", T.StringType(), True),
                          T.StructField("Dept", T.StringType(), True),
                          ])


rows = sc.parallelize([("priy", "345", "cse"),\
                            ("james", "NA", np.nan),\
                            (None, "567", "NULL")])

myDF = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

myDF.show()
+-----+-----+----+
| Name|RolNo|Dept|
+-----+-----+----+
| priy|  345| cse|
|james|   NA| NaN|
| null|  567|NULL|
+-----+-----+----+

# gives you a count of nans, nulls, specific string values, etc for each col
myDF = myDF.select([F.count(F.when(F.isnan(i) | \
                                   F.col(i).contains('NA') | \
                                   F.col(i).contains('NULL') | \
                                   F.col(i).isNull(), i)).alias(i) \
                    for i in myDF.columns])

myDF.show()
+----+-----+----+
|Name|RolNo|Dept|
+----+-----+----+
|   1|    1|   2|
+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: im reading a csv file with custom schema .if one column has null value which results entire row as null values

Comment: it doesn't matter if you are reading csv, json, parquet, avro the query I provided gives you the counts of  "null,na and nan values in each column of pyspark dataframe" like you asked for in your question.

Comment: If you want to count values equal to zero, simply add `(F.col(i) == 0)` after `|`. Round brackets are important because it is understood as `(F.col(i).isNull() | F.col(i)) == 0`,  and results in `AnalysisException` (maybe because of the incompatible data types)